# Problemas con la instalación del Angular -common

Tags: angular

estoy teniendo problemas al instalar el angular en mi equipo. Sistema Operativo Zorin 15.1.

He realizado la instalación de acuerdo a varias paginas web, sin embargo me sale:

```
$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
$ ng -v
$ No se ha encontrado la orden «ng», pero se puede instalar con:

sudo apt install ng-common
```

Sin embargo al instalar el ng-common, me sale al pedir la version:

Mg++ version:
    Mg++ 1.5beta1 (formerly MicroGnuEmacs Adv.)

He realizado instalación/desinstalación del node, pero no me soluciona.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Debes instalar node en su ultima version si es que no lo tienes. Luego actualiza NPM 
`npm install -g npm@latest`
Vacia la cache
`npm cache clean --force`
Se vacian auditorias
`npm set audit false`
Para evitar problemas desintala las otras versiones de angular que tengas instaladas
`npm uninstall -g angular-cli`
`npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
Si luego de esto te tira error vacia nuevamente la cache e instala la ultima version
`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Comment: Perfecto Franco, funciono a las mil maravillas. Mil Gracias por compartir una solucion.